# Check file exists in source before copying

Tags: powershell

I have list of files, I am trying to copy to another location.

```
$files = @("abc.ps1", "def.ps1")
$scriptFiles | Copy-Item -Destination "destinationlocation" -Force
```

So I get an error when file abc.ps1 is not availalbe, Is there a way to `Test-Path` by avoiding to write a loop and write in single line?

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? Why does it have to be one line? The variable names differ.

Comment: I am learning it so for knowledge purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out the ones that don't exist with `Test-Path` in `Where` clause.

```
$files = @("abc.ps1", "def.ps1")
$files | Where { Test-Path $_ } | ForEach { $file = Get-Item $_; Copy-Item "destinationlocation\$_" -Force; }
```

Or shorthand version of the same script:

```
$files = @("abc.ps1", "def.ps1")
$files | ?{ Test-Path $_ } | %{ $file = gi $_; cp $file.FullName "destinationlocation\$_" -Force; }
```

Comment: Nice, but you can pipe directly to `Copy-Item` - no need for `ForEach-Object`.